# Function echos variable correctly to ajax file but in html doesn't show anything

Tags: javascript, php, variables, hover, wordpress-featured-image

**Php variable `$testing` correctly echos ajax file, but in html `<?php echo $testing;?>` doesn't show anything.**

**html:**

```
<?php
    get_header();
    ?>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        
    var hrefValue;
    
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('#bio-box').find('a').mouseover(function() {
            hrefValue = ($(this).attr('href'));
            $.ajax({
                url: '/jakubtrz-portfolio/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
                data: {
                    'action': 'php_tutorial',
                    'php_test': hrefValue
                },
                success: function(data){
                    console.log("sent")
                }
            });
        });
    }); 
    
    </script>
    
    <?php echo $testing;?>
    
    <main id="primary" class="site-main">
    <div class="container position-relative my-7">
    
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6" id="bio-box">
                <a href="http://localhost:8888/jakubtrz-portfolio/quod-si-ita-se-habeat-non-possit/">Example post link</a>
                <a href="http://localhost:8888/jakubtrz-portfolio/quid-ergo-aliud-intellege/">Example post link2</a>
            </div>
    
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="featured-image">
                    <?php 
                        $post_id = url_to_postid($testing);
                        echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id);
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
    </div>
    </main><!-- #main -->
    
    <?php
    get_footer();
```

**functions.php:**

```
function our_tutorial(){
        if(isset($_REQUEST)){
            $testing = $_REQUEST['php_test'];
    
            echo $testing;
    
            global $wpdb;
            $wpdb->insert(
                $wpdb->prefix.'lms_enroll',
                [
                    'ID' => $testing
                ]
            );
    
        }
        die();
    }
    add_action('wp_ajax_php_tutorial', 'our_tutorial');
```

Comment: PHP runs when the page is created on the server, before the AJAX call happens. The AJAX call can't change PHP variables on the page that's sending the request.

Comment: `<?php echo $testing;?> doesn't show anything`...have you checked in the console? Because that's the only place you've instructed your JavaScript to output it to. It's unclear why you expect it to appear anywhere else, unless you've fundamentally misunderstood how Ajax works

Comment: @ADyson Yes as I said function outputs variable data. Probably I miss understood because I thought it will work also in html. So I’m wondering now what to do to get this data into html. Or in general what should I do to show those featured images thumbnails on hover…

Comment: To get the output of an Ajax request into your page you must write JavaScript code which puts it into the document in the place you want it. You can use the standard JavaScript or jQuery DOM manipulation functions for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to add `$('#featured-image').html(data);` to the script, which pass the data output to html.

```
var hrefValue;
    
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('#bio-box').find('a').mouseover(function() {
            hrefValue = ($(this).attr('href'))
            //console.log(hrefValue)
            $.ajax({
                url: frontendajax.ajaxurl,
                type: 'POST', 
                data: {
                    'action': 'image',
                    'php_test': hrefValue
                },
                success: function(data){
                    $('#featured-image').html(data);
                    //console.log(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

also moved php lines from html to function.php:

```
function fimg() {
    if ( isset( $_POST['php_test'] ) ) {
        $testing = sanitize_text_field( wp_unslash( $_POST['php_test'] ) );
        $post_id = url_to_postid( $testing );
        echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id );
    }
    die();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_image', 'fimg' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_image', 'fimg' );
```

I missunderstood how ajax works. The simplest answer imo is this diagram: [image]

Comment: Great answer, especially the diagram. Glad you got it all sorted out